# Sending build context to Docker daemon (it doesn't stop)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

(UBUNTU) I create my dockerfile with `touch dockerfile` and I do `sudo vim dockerfile`. the code inside is:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.00
CMD echo Hello World!!
```

So I do `sudo docker build .` . The shell prints me

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon TOT kB
```

TOT is the number of GB that the shell download and Now I have 10.40 GB. IS it possible or I wrong something?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`mv` your Dockerfile to an empty folder, and build it. 
When build a docker image, docker will "use" all files in current folder as its "context".
You can also create a `.dockerignore` file to exclude files or directories like `.gitignore`.

Comment: To be a bit more specific: all files in current folder **and** subfolders.

Comment: I stopped the process at around 100 GB before I found this answer. Is this data cached somewhere, eating up my harddrive? If so, is there a way to find and trash it?

Comment: Moving my Dockerfile to an empty folder and building it solved my problem (from taking forever to a few seconds.)

Answer (score 4):

Try this command :

```
docker build -t go_grpc:1.10 - < Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 0):

For me above steps did not work, so i had to kill most of the docker daemon processes [I was using colima]

```
pfkill -f 'colima'
```

or

```
pfkill -f 'docker'
```

And then running `docker build -t <name> .`